# Call a function without the element thats bound to

Tags: jquery, function, triggers

I have a function bound to a button that looks like this:

```
$(".deletebutton").click(function(sender){...somecode...}
```

In another function (Let's call it function_2) i want do do the same thing that happenes in the click-funktion. Now i dont want to use

> `$( ".button" ).trigger( "click" );`

because within the click-function i have to distinguish, if the function is called by pressing the button or by calling it in function_2.

Can anyone help me there?

Note: Sorry if the title may be misleading, i didnt know how to say it better in english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can isolate your function. In this case you will be able to call it onclick and on any other event. Something like this:

```
function someName(){...somecode...}

$(".deletebutton").click(someName());

function function_2(){
   ...some code...
   someName();
   ...some code...
}
```

Comment: Simple and perfct. Thank you!